# array of objects group them by a specific key

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following array

```
const arr = [{
  agrupacion: "Total país",
  valor: "81.8",
  year: 2015
}, {
  agrupacion: "Total país",
  valor: "86.4",
  year: 2016
}, {
  agrupacion: "Total país",
  valor: "67.3",
  year: 2017
}, {
  agrupacion: "Total país",
  valor: "70.8",
  year: 2018
}, {
  agrupacion: "Total país",
  valor: "67.6",
  year: 2019
}, {
  agrupacion: "Oriental",
  valor: "78.6",
  year: 2015
}, {
  agrupacion: "Oriental",
  valor: "83.1",
  year: 2016
}, {
  agrupacion: "Oriental",
  valor: "65.6",
  year: 2017
}, {
  agrupacion: "Oriental",
  valor: "68.1",
  year: 2018
}, {
  agrupacion: "Oriental",
  valor: "63.7",
  year: 2019
}, {
  agrupacion: "Occidental",
  valor: "177.3",
  year: 2015
}, {
  agrupacion: "Occidental",
  valor: "182.9",
  year: 2016
}, {
  agrupacion: "Occidental",
  valor: "114.3",
  year: 2017
}, {
  agrupacion: "Occidental",
  valor: "144.5",
  year: 2018
}, {
  agrupacion: "Occidental",
  valor: "169.9",
  year: 2019
}, {
  agrupacion: "Urbano",
  valor: "79.6",
  year: 2015
}, {
  agrupacion: "Urbano",
  valor: "92.5",
  year: 2016
}, {
  agrupacion: "Urbano",
  valor: "62.1",
  year: 2017
}, {
  agrupacion: "Urbano",
  valor: "82.2",
  year: 2018
}, {
  agrupacion: "Urbano",
  valor: "80.6",
  year: 2019
}, {
  agrupacion: "Rural",
  valor: "86.5",
  year: 2015
}, {
  agrupacion: "Rural",
  valor: "63.7",
  year: 2016
}, {
  agrupacion: "Rural",
  valor: "87.2",
  year: 2017
}, {
  agrupacion: "Rural",
  valor: "45.7",
  year: 2018
}, {
  agrupacion: "Rural",
  valor: "38.9",
  year: 2019
}];
```

I used this method to achieve what I wanted:

```
const groups = new Map(arr.map(({agrupacion}) => [agrupacion, { agrupacion }]));
for (const {agrupacion, valor, year} of arr) {
    groups.get(agrupacion)["col" + year] = +valor;
}

const result = [...groups.values()];
```

the output is (console.log(result )):

```
[{
  agrupacion: "Total país",
  col2015: 81.8,
  col2016: 86.4,
  col2017: 67.3,
  col2018: 70.8,
  col2019: 67.6
}, {
  agrupacion: "Oriental",
  col2015: 78.6,
  col2016: 83.1,
  col2017: 65.6,
  col2018: 68.1,
  col2019: 63.7
}, {
  agrupacion: "Occidental",
  col2015: 177.3,
  col2016: 182.9,
  col2017: 114.3,
  col2018: 144.5,
  col2019: 169.9
}, {
  agrupacion: "Urbano",
  col2015: 79.6,
  col2016: 92.5,
  col2017: 62.1,
  col2018: 82.2,
  col2019: 80.6
}, {
  agrupacion: "Rural",
  col2015: 86.5,
  col2016: 63.7,
  col2017: 87.2,
  col2018: 45.7,
  col2019: 38.9
}];
```

That output is the format I need however the problem comes when I add additional data with the same "agrupacion" value to my arr array, for example I add this at the end of my arr array

```
,{
  agrupacion: "Total país",
  valor: "151",
  year: 2015
}, {
  agrupacion: "Total país",
  valor: "184",
  year: 2016
}, {
  agrupacion: "Total país",
  valor: "165",
  year: 2017
}, {
  agrupacion: "Total país",
  valor: "147",
  year: 2018
}, {
  agrupacion: "Total país",
  valor: "190",
  year: 2019
}
```

This is what I need:

```
[{
  agrupacion: "Total país",
  col2015: 81.8,
  col2016: 86.4,
  col2017: 67.3,
  col2018: 70.8,
  col2019: 67.6
}, {
  agrupacion: "Oriental",
  col2015: 78.6,
  col2016: 83.1,
  col2017: 65.6,
  col2018: 68.1,
  col2019: 63.7
}, {
  agrupacion: "Occidental",
  col2015: 177.3,
  col2016: 182.9,
  col2017: 114.3,
  col2018: 144.5,
  col2019: 169.9
}, {
  agrupacion: "Urbano",
  col2015: 79.6,
  col2016: 92.5,
  col2017: 62.1,
  col2018: 82.2,
  col2019: 80.6
}, {
  agrupacion: "Rural",
  col2015: 86.5,
  col2016: 63.7,
  col2017: 87.2,
  col2018: 45.7,
  col2019: 38.9
},{
  agrupacion: "Total país",
  col2015: 151,
  col2016: 184,
  col2017: 165,
  col2018: 147,
  col2019: 190
}];
```

This is what I get with my attempt:

```
[{
  agrupacion: "Total país",
  col2015: 151,
  col2016: 184,
  col2017: 165,
  col2018: 147,
  col2019: 190
}, {
  agrupacion: "Oriental",
  col2015: 78.6,
  col2016: 83.1,
  col2017: 65.6,
  col2018: 68.1,
  col2019: 63.7
}, {
  agrupacion: "Occidental",
  col2015: 177.3,
  col2016: 182.9,
  col2017: 114.3,
  col2018: 144.5,
  col2019: 169.9
}, {
  agrupacion: "Urbano",
  col2015: 79.6,
  col2016: 92.5,
  col2017: 62.1,
  col2018: 82.2,
  col2019: 80.6
}, {
  agrupacion: "Rural",
  col2015: 86.5,
  col2016: 63.7,
  col2017: 87.2,
  col2018: 45.7,
  col2019: 38.9
}]
```

Apparently it overwrites all the values from the first "Total país" rather than repeating that agrupacion with the new values that I added

Comment: Place this: `groups.get(agrupacion)["col" + year] = +valor;` within an `if` block with the condition that `groups` does not already have the `agrupacion` with the `"col" + year` prop. Then, only the first `Total Pais` will be stored & subsequent ones will be discarded.

Comment: @jsN00b I actually need it to store all of them, even if there is a second and third "Total Pais"

Comment: Does your data always come in fives?

Comment: @PeterKA sometimes it varies but if it come in fives then that means that all the elements in the current array will come like that. sometimes it comes with six values but that means that every other element will have 6 in it as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reduce the array into an object where the keys correspond to the `agrupacion` and the values correspond to an array of objects. And the length of this array is decided based on how many times an year appears for a particular `agrupacion`.

So, the following array:

```
[
  { agrupacion: "Total país", valor: "81.8", year: 2015 },
  { agrupacion: "Total país", valor: "86.4", year: 2016 },
  { agrupacion: "Total país", valor: "67.3", year: 2015 },
  { agrupacion: "Oriental", valor: "78.6", year: 2015 },
]
```

Is reduced into the following object:

```
{
  "Total país": [
    { agrupacion: "Total país", col2015: 81.8, col2016: 86.4 },
    { agrupacion: "Total país", col2015: 67.3 },
  ],
  Oriental: [{ agrupacion: "Oriental", col2015: 78.6 }],
}
```

And finally we get the values of this object and flatten it to the desired result.

```js
const arr = [
  { agrupacion: "Total país", valor: "81.8", year: 2015 },
  { agrupacion: "Total país", valor: "86.4", year: 2016 },
  { agrupacion: "Total país", valor: "67.3", year: 2017 },
  { agrupacion: "Total país", valor: "70.8", year: 2018 },
  { agrupacion: "Total país", valor: "67.6", year: 2019 },
  { agrupacion: "Oriental", valor: "78.6", year: 2015 },
  { agrupacion: "Oriental", valor: "83.1", year: 2016 },
  { agrupacion: "Oriental", valor: "65.6", year: 2017 },
  { agrupacion: "Oriental", valor: "68.1", year: 2018 },
  { agrupacion: "Oriental", valor: "63.7", year: 2019 },
  { agrupacion: "Occidental", valor: "177.3", year: 2015 },
  { agrupacion: "Occidental", valor: "182.9", year: 2016 },
  { agrupacion: "Occidental", valor: "114.3", year: 2017 },
  { agrupacion: "Occidental", valor: "144.5", year: 2018 },
  { agrupacion: "Occidental", valor: "169.9", year: 2019 },
  { agrupacion: "Urbano", valor: "79.6", year: 2015 },
  { agrupacion: "Urbano", valor: "92.5", year: 2016 },
  { agrupacion: "Urbano", valor: "62.1", year: 2017 },
  { agrupacion: "Urbano", valor: "82.2", year: 2018 },
  { agrupacion: "Urbano", valor: "80.6", year: 2019 },
  { agrupacion: "Rural", valor: "86.5", year: 2015 },
  { agrupacion: "Rural", valor: "63.7", year: 2016 },
  { agrupacion: "Rural", valor: "87.2", year: 2017 },
  { agrupacion: "Rural", valor: "45.7", year: 2018 },
  { agrupacion: "Rural", valor: "38.9", year: 2019 },
  { agrupacion: "Total país", valor: "151", year: 2015 },
  { agrupacion: "Total país", valor: "184", year: 2016 },
  { agrupacion: "Total país", valor: "165", year: 2017 },
  { agrupacion: "Total país", valor: "147", year: 2018 },
  { agrupacion: "Total país", valor: "190", year: 2019 },
];

const result = Object.values(
  arr.reduce((r, o) => {
    if (!r[o.agrupacion]) {
      r[o.agrupacion] = [{ agrupacion: o.agrupacion }];
    }
    const item = r[o.agrupacion].find((i) => !i["col" + o.year]);
    if (item) {
      item["col" + o.year] = parseFloat(o.valor);
    } else {
      r[o.agrupacion].push({
        agrupacion: o.agrupacion,
        ["col" + o.year]: parseFloat(o.valor),
      });
    }
    return r;
  }, {})
).flat();

console.log(result);
```

Comment: This one does the job, is there a way to convert the numeric string values with parseFloat() within the function?

Comment: @ChrisG Yes, I've updated my answer, please take a look!

Answer (score 2):

Try this forEach function :

```
 let arrayBuild = []
      let results = []
      let currentAgrupacion = ''
      let element = {}
      
      arr.forEach(elem => {
        if(currentAgrupacion !== elem.agrupacion) {
          if(currentAgrupacion !== '') {
            results.push(element)
          }
          currentAgrupacion = elem.agrupacion
          element = {
            agrupacion: elem.agrupacion
          }
      element["col"+elem.year] = parseFloat(elem.valor)
    }
    else {
      element["col"+elem.year] = parseFloat(elem.valor)
    }
  })
  results.push(element)

  console.log(results)
```

Comment: Is not working on my demo https://jsfiddle.net/kenpy/er3ztdnx/4/

Comment: Just edited the answer. Wan't working in your fiddle cause this solution use named element in array

Comment: ty, it is working now however it has the same problem that my attempt has. It overwrites the values that I stored first and leaves only the last ones

Comment: Okay so now it won't overwrite the Total pais group but add another one

Answer (score 0):

You could keep track of the last `yearData` (the group of data you're collecting). If a given `col<year>` is already present within this object, create a new object.

```
const result = [];
let yearData;
for (const {agrupacion, valor, year} of arr) {
  const colYear = `col${year}`;
  if (!yearData || colYear in yearData) {
    yearData = { agrupacion };
    result.push(yearData);
  }
  yearData[colYear] = +valor;
}
```

```js
const arr = [
  { agrupacion: "Total país", valor: "81.8",  year: 2015 },
  { agrupacion: "Total país", valor: "86.4",  year: 2016 },
  { agrupacion: "Total país", valor: "67.3",  year: 2017 },
  { agrupacion: "Total país", valor: "70.8",  year: 2018 },
  { agrupacion: "Total país", valor: "67.6",  year: 2019 },
  { agrupacion: "Oriental",   valor: "78.6",  year: 2015 },
  { agrupacion: "Oriental",   valor: "83.1",  year: 2016 },
  { agrupacion: "Oriental",   valor: "65.6",  year: 2017 },
  { agrupacion: "Oriental",   valor: "68.1",  year: 2018 },
  { agrupacion: "Oriental",   valor: "63.7",  year: 2019 },
  { agrupacion: "Occidental", valor: "177.3", year: 2015 },
  { agrupacion: "Occidental", valor: "182.9", year: 2016 },
  { agrupacion: "Occidental", valor: "114.3", year: 2017 },
  { agrupacion: "Occidental", valor: "144.5", year: 2018 },
  { agrupacion: "Occidental", valor: "169.9", year: 2019 },
  { agrupacion: "Urbano",     valor: "79.6",  year: 2015 },
  { agrupacion: "Urbano",     valor: "92.5",  year: 2016 },
  { agrupacion: "Urbano",     valor: "62.1",  year: 2017 },
  { agrupacion: "Urbano",     valor: "82.2",  year: 2018 },
  { agrupacion: "Urbano",     valor: "80.6",  year: 2019 },
  { agrupacion: "Rural",      valor: "86.5",  year: 2015 },
  { agrupacion: "Rural",      valor: "63.7",  year: 2016 },
  { agrupacion: "Rural",      valor: "87.2",  year: 2017 },
  { agrupacion: "Rural",      valor: "45.7",  year: 2018 },
  { agrupacion: "Rural",      valor: "38.9",  year: 2019 },
  { agrupacion: "Total país", valor: "151",   year: 2015 },
  { agrupacion: "Total país", valor: "184",   year: 2016 },
  { agrupacion: "Total país", valor: "165",   year: 2017 },
  { agrupacion: "Total país", valor: "147",   year: 2018 },
  { agrupacion: "Total país", valor: "190",   year: 2019 },
];

const result = [];
let yearData;
for (const { agrupacion, valor, year } of arr) {
  const colYear = `col${year}`;
  if (!yearData || colYear in yearData) {
    yearData = { agrupacion };
    result.push(yearData);
  }
  yearData[colYear] = +valor;
}

console.log(result);
```

The answer does assume a certain consistency in `arr`. Namely that each group of items share the exact same year range (2015-2019 in your data), and there are no missing years.

An example of an inconsistent input that produces a wrong output is:

```
const arr = [
  { agrupacion: "a", valor: "1", year: 2015 },
  { agrupacion: "a", valor: "2", year: 2016 },
  { agrupacion: "a", valor: "3", year: 2017 },
  { agrupacion: "b", valor: "4", year: 2015 },
  // 2016 missing
  { agrupacion: "b", valor: "5", year: 2017 },
  // 2015 missing
  { agrupacion: "c", valor: "6", year: 2016 },
  { agrupacion: "c", valor: "7", year: 2017 },
];
```

Which results in:

```
[
  { agrupacion: "a", col2015: 1, col2016: 2, col2017: 3 },
  { agrupacion: "b", col2015: 4, col2016: 6, col2017: 5 },
  { agrupacion: "c",                         col2017: 7 },
]
```

If these gaps in data can occur you'll want to change:

```
if (!yearData || colYear in yearData)
```

Into:

```
if (!yearData || agrupacion != yearData.agrupacion || colYear in yearData)
```

To ensure that a new `yearData` object is used if either `agrupacion` is different or `col<year>` is already present.